# SQL datetime update time to 00:00:00 from all other time values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, milliseconds

Is there a way to update all columns in table from

```
2010-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

to

```
2010-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Something like this??

```
UPDATE t1
SET [Posting Date] = [Posting Date] with ms = 00:00:00.000
WHERE ms = other than 00:00:00.000
GO
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET [Posting Date] = cast([Posting Date] as date)
WHERE cast([Posting Date] as time) > '00:00'
```

Comment: i-one´s solution works, but I asked for the where condition. Thus accepting this as the final answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE t1
SET [Posting Date] = CAST([Posting Date] as DATE)
```

Answer (score 5):

This may help you:

`UPDATE tableName SET ColumnName =  CAST( CAST( NOW( ) AS DATE ) AS DATETIME );`

Answer (score 0):

in sq-server

```
UPDATE [dbo].[1] SET  [datetime]= CAST([datetime] AS DATE) 

select * from [dbo].[1]
```

Comment: i didnt check the question correctly mybad,now it's correct !!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MODIFIEDDATETIME-(cast(MODIFIEDDATETIME as time))
```

Comment: The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
update t1 set [Posting Date]  = CONVERT(varchar,[Posting Date] , 112)
```

But I suposse it deppends heavily on how are the locale of your database configured, you could need to use another style (instead 112, perhaps 101 or 102...) see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to see the possible style for the conversion and choose the one that suits you better.

Alternative if you need to do this once, you could change the column type to date, save and then back to datetime, but if the table is big this could be time consuming

Comment: never ever use this solution. You already have a datetime, don't abuse it by converting to varchar

Comment: I know is a fast and dirty solution, but it never gave me any problem